# Problems filling a container with video via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to create a full background video using jquery on a new page, but I am having issues filling an existing container on a page with the video. I am looking to be able to use this code to add the video to a couple of different containers on a single page. Such as a section and the hero unit. Although for now I am just trying to figure out how to add it to the hero unit and I can go from there. I tried replacing all videobg class and videobg_wrapper classes with the hero class, although it still isn't working.

Can anyone assist me? Any help would be appreciated. Here is a jfiddle with the jquery and css class.

Jfiddle with code: http://jsfiddle.net/NN276/12/

Fullscreen Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NN276/12/embedded/result/

Here is an attempt to change videobg to the hero class:

```
(function( $ ){

        $.fn.videoBG = function( selector, options ) { 

            var options = {};
            if (typeof selector == "object") {
                options = $.extend({}, $.fn.videoBG.defaults, selector);
            }
            else if (!selector) {
                options = $.fn.videoBG.defaults;
            }
            else {
                return $(selector).videoBG(options);        
            }

            var container = $(this);

            // check if elements available otherwise it will cause issues
            if (!container.length)
                return;

            // container to be at least relative
            if (container.css('position') == 'static' || !container.css('position'))
                container.css('position','relative');

            // we need a width
            if (options.width == 0)
                options.width = container.width();

            // we need a height
            if (options.height == 0)
                options.height = container.height();    

            // get the wrapper
            var wrap = $.fn.videoBG.wrapper();
            wrap.height(options.height)
                .width(options.width);

            // if is a text replacement
            if (options.textReplacement) {

                // force sizes
                options.scale = true;

                // set sizes and forcing text out
                container.width(options.width)
                    .height(options.height)
                    .css('text-indent','-9999px');
            }
            else {

                // set the wrapper above the video
                wrap.css('z-index',options.zIndex+1);
            }

            // move the contents into the wrapper
            wrap.html(container.clone(true));

            // get the video
            var video = $.fn.videoBG.video(options);

            // if we are forcing width / height
            if (options.scale) {

                // overlay wrapper
                wrap.height(options.height)
                    .width(options.width);

                // video
                video.height(options.height)
                    .width(options.width);
            }

            // add it all to the container
            container.html(wrap);
            container.append(video);

            return video.find("video")[0];
        }

        // set to fullscreen
        $.fn.videoBG.setFullscreen = function($el) {
            var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
                windowHeight = $(window).height();

            $el.css('min-height',0).css('min-width',0);
            $el.parent().width(windowWidth).height(windowHeight);
            // if by width 
            if (windowWidth / windowHeight > $el.aspectRatio) {
                $el.width(windowWidth).height('auto');
                // shift the element up
                var height = $el.height();
                var shift = (height - windowHeight) / 2;
                if (shift < 0) shift = 0;
                $el.css("top",-shift);
            } else {
                $el.width('auto').height(windowHeight);         
                // shift the element left
                var width = $el.width();
                var shift = (width - windowWidth) / 2;
                if (shift < 0) shift = 0;
                $el.css("left",-shift);

                // this is a hack mainly due to the iphone
                if (shift === 0) {
                    var t = setTimeout(function() {
                        $.fn.videoBG.setFullscreen($el);
                    },500);
                }
            }

            $('body > .hero').width(windowWidth).height(windowHeight);

        }

        // get the formatted video element
        $.fn.videoBG.video = function(options) {

            $('html, body').scrollTop(-1);

            // video container
            var $div = $('<div/>');
            $div.addClass(hero')
                .css('position',options.position)
                .css('z-index',options.zIndex)
                .css('top',0)
                .css('left',0)
                .css('height',options.height)
                .css('width',options.width)
                .css('opacity',options.opacity)
                .css('overflow','hidden');

            // video element
            var $video = $('<video/>');
            $video.css('position','absolute')
                .css('z-index',options.zIndex)
                .attr('poster',options.poster)
                .css('top',0)
                .css('left',0)
                .css('min-width','100%')
                .css('min-height','100%');

            if (options.autoplay) {
                $video.attr('autoplay',options.autoplay);
            }

            // if fullscreen
            if (options.fullscreen) {
                $video.bind('canplay',function() {
                    // set the aspect ratio
                    $video.aspectRatio = $video.width() / $video.height();
                    $.fn.videoBG.setFullscreen($video);
                })

                // listen out for screenresize
                var resizeTimeout;
                $(window).resize(function() {
                    clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
                    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        $.fn.videoBG.setFullscreen($video);
                    },100); 
                });
                $.fn.videoBG.setFullscreen($video);
            }


            // video standard element
            var v = $video[0];

            // if meant to loop
            if (options.loop) {
                loops_left = options.loop;

                // cant use the loop attribute as firefox doesnt support it
                $video.bind('ended', function(){

                    // if we have some loops to throw
                    if (loops_left)
                        // replay that bad boy
                        v.play();

                    // if not forever
                    if (loops_left !== true)
                        // one less loop
                        loops_left--;
                });
            }

            // when can play, play
            $video.bind('canplay', function(){

                if (options.autoplay)
                    // replay that bad boy
                    v.play();

            });


            // if supports video
            if ($.fn.videoBG.supportsVideo()) {

                // supports webm
                if ($.fn.videoBG.supportType('webm')){

                    // play webm
                    $video.attr('src',options.webm);
                }
                // supports mp4
                else if ($.fn.videoBG.supportType('mp4')) {     

                    // play mp4
                    $video.attr('src',options.mp4);

                //  $video.html('<source src="'.options.mp4.'" />');

                }
                // throw ogv at it then
                else {

                    // play ogv
                    $video.attr('src',options.ogv);
                }

            }



            // image for those that dont support the video  
            var $img = $('<img/>');
            $img.attr('src',options.poster)
                .css('position','absolute')
                .css('z-index',options.zIndex)
                .css('top',0)
                .css('left',0)
                .css('min-width','100%')
                .css('min-height','100%');

            // add the image to the video
            // if suuports video
            if ($.fn.videoBG.supportsVideo()) {
                // add the video to the wrapper
                $div.html($video);
            }

            // nope - whoa old skool
            else {

                // add the image instead
                $div.html($img);
            }

            // if text replacement
            if (options.textReplacement) {

                // force the heights and widths
                $div.css('min-height',1).css('min-width',1);
                $video.css('min-height',1).css('min-width',1);
                $img.css('min-height',1).css('min-width',1);

                $div.height(options.height).width(options.width);
                $video.height(options.height).width(options.width);
                $img.height(options.height).width(options.width);   
            }

            if ($.fn.videoBG.supportsVideo()) {
                v.play();
            }
            return $div;
        }

        // check if suuports video
        $.fn.videoBG.supportsVideo = function() {
            return (document.createElement('video').canPlayType);
        }

        // check which type is supported
        $.fn.videoBG.supportType = function(str) {

            // if not at all supported
            if (!$.fn.videoBG.supportsVideo())
                return false;

            // create video
            var v = document.createElement('video');

            // check which?
            switch (str) {
                case 'webm' :
                    return (v.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'));
                    break;
                case 'mp4' :
                    return (v.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'));
                    break;
                case 'ogv' :
                    return (v.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'));
                    break;          
            }
            // nope
            return false;   
        }

        // get the overlay wrapper
        $.fn.videoBG.wrapper = function() {
            var $wrap = $('<div/>');
            $wrap.addClass('videoBG_wrapper')
                .css('position','absolute')
                .css('top',0)
                .css('left',0);
            return $wrap;
        }

        // these are the defaults
        $.fn.videoBG.defaults = {
                mp4:'',
                ogv:'',
                webm:'',
                poster:'',
                autoplay:true,
                loop:true,
                scale:false,
                position:"absolute",
                opacity:1,
                textReplacement:false,
                zIndex:0,
                width:0,
                height:0,
                fullscreen:false,
                imgFallback:true
            }

    })( jQuery );



    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('body').videoBG({
            position:"fixed",
            zIndex:0,
            mp4:'http://www.pete.dj/video/video.mp4',
            ogv:'http://www.pete.dj/video/video.ogv',
            webm:'http://www.pete.dj/video/video.webm',
            opacity:1,
            fullscreen:true,
        });

    })
```

Comment: Are you trying to add multiple instances of the same video or multiple different videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the complete solution as they all don't play immediately, but somewhere to start.

```
$('.hero').each(function() {
    $(this).videoBG({
        position:"relative",
        zIndex:0,
        mp4:'http://www.pete.dj/video/video.mp4',
        ogv:'http://www.pete.dj/video/video.ogv',
        webm:'http://www.pete.dj/video/video.webm',
        opacity:1,
        fullscreen:false,
    }); 
});
```

**Working JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/NN276/15/

Also, the creator provides the [following warning on his plugin site](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/).

> Don't abuse this code... Don't use it too often, too many video
>   instances will slow down the browser.
>
> Please bear in mind bandwidth usage for both you, and your visitors